# How to solve "RadAsyncUpload does not have permission to write files in the TemporaryFolder. ..."

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, webforms, telerik

My WebApp(asp.net WebForm C#) is working properly but when i uploaded it, telerik's radgrid is working properly but RadAsyncUpload is giving me following error.

> RadAsyncUpload does not have permission to write files
>   in the TemporaryFolder. In Medium Trust scenarios, the TemporaryFolder
>   should be a subfolder of the Application Path.

i found that

> UseApplicationPoolImpersonation and impersonate="true" in the
>   web.config

will solve the problem but under what tag i should add it? by the way i am new to IIS7.

Answer (score 2):

For me the issue was resolved after going into IIS folder where the site files are located, and ensuring that the folder has "Modify" and "Full Control" permissions for Users.

[image]

Comment: In my case checked  to `IIS_IUSRS`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows authentication, you want to put this inside your `<system.web>`

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\username" password="mypassword" />
```

If you're using Anonymous auth, you don't need the userName or password.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I happen to stumble upon this problem today. Before I was told by a console message that a path "RadUploadTemp\RadUploadTestFile" was not found. So I created those two folders. And that was the mistake, as I [learned from this one](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-solve-radasyncupload-does-not-have-permission-to-write-after-adding-suggestion). Once I deleted RadUploadTestFile catalogue it started working. RadUploadTestFile is a file created automatically, not a folder.